Constituency tests
Determine whether "down the radio" in the following sentence is a constituent by using any of the following tests: substitution and movement. If it is NOT a constituent, you need to identify what the constituent is in "the girl turned down the radio."
I asked my friends and they told me that in terms of substitution test, "it" can replace "down the radio" and we have "the girl turned it". For movement test, "Down the radio, the girl turned." is grammatically acceptable but others said this movement results in a grammatically awkward sentence, suggesting that "down the radio" may not be a constituent.
I'm really confused and need your help.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The community might be able to better help you if you point our more precisely where you're confused. You can [edit] your question to say what you've found so far and what still confuses you.

You have misparsed the sentence. It is not "down the radio". The phrasal verb is: to turn something down or to turn down something. It means: to reduce the volume.

Sample sentence: "The girl turned down the radio."
The first order of business here is to parse the sentence.
To parse, we will first see what a constituent is.
The Science of Syntax Copyright © by John Gluckman defines it:
[For our purposes here, his definition below is fine.]

When I claim that a string of words is a constituent, I’m claiming
that all of those words are grouped together under one label. Note
that a single word, is, by definition, a constituent. A sentence is
also, by definition, a constituent. What I’m ultimately trying to do
when I figure out constituency is I’m trying figure out how
information is packaged. How does any language put its pieces together
to make a meaningful utterance?
Precisely, in any given language, I want to know which words go with
which words. This allows me to write the simplest possible rules. For
instance, with our DP rule, I can capture the idea that The mailman
slept and The happy mailman slept  both involve a subject and verb.
Identifying The mailman and The happy mailman as the same “thing”
simplifies my understanding—and representation—of the English
language. I can reduce sentences to grammatical roles like
Subject-Verb, or Subject-Verb-Object by identifying that the the term
“subject” may involve something that consists of more than one word,
like the happy mailman.

To show the constituents, we can divide the sentence into groups of words, or parse it:
"The girl turned down the radio." [six constitutents]
One cannot remove a phrase from that before one parses it. So, "down the radio" is not a phrase in that utterance.
The constituent parts of it are this:
"The.girl/ turned down/ the.radio." [Subject_Verb_Object: SVO] [Also, the is a determiner in both instances, but that is not strictly relevant to us here.
What stands out here to an English speaker is that to turn down means to reduce the volume [of sound]* from some source.
Substitution of turned down by reduce the volume works.

The girl reduced the volume of the radio.

The girl turned down the radio. Those two mean the same thing.


Also, "it" can be substituted for "the radio" but its position changes (moves).
The girl turned it down.
turn down (reduce the volume) is a separable phrasal verb in English. That means you can use:

The girl turned down the radio.
OR
The girl turned the radio down.

BUT: if you use "it", as the object in a separable verb, it has to go between turn and down = The girl turned it down.
Other separable ones with turn include: turn up, turn around
A non-separable phrasal verb is: get up, get down, go around, turn back (from a direction, not turn back the clock, which is separable), etc.
So, to answer the question: All the words in that utterance (sentence) are its constituents. However, the parse (correction separation or division into parts) "down the radio" is not correct but /turn down/ the radio is a constituent phrase of it.

I'd say turn around is not phrasal, at least in all senses; “turn the chair around” and “turn around the chair” do not mean the same to me.

@AntonSherwood I said that turn around is a separable phrasal verb: He turned the economy around. He turned around the economy. "Turn the chair around" is a verb + a prepositional phrase.

Yes, you said that, and I disagreed.  “turned around the economy” is weird to me.

Well, you are mistaken. //The relief and stimulus measures enacted in 2020 supported aggregate demand — which fell rapidly after the crisis hit early that year — and turned the economy around, putting it on the road to recovery. https://www.cbpp.org/research/economy/inflation-concerns-should-not-impede-enactment-of-build-back-better

Which is not an example of “turned around the economy”.

MR. HELBLING: Yes, the Chinese economy is on track. There are no revisions to the forecast. I think the policy support has turned around the economy as expected. World Bank https://www.imf.org/en/News/Articles/2015/09/28/04/54/tr012313 And this:  But since that’s what turned around the economy in World War Two, wiped out 9 percent unemployment, and finally ended the Great Depression, goes the argument, then that’s the scale of spending that is required now. https://www.aei.org/articles/the-ultimate-stimulus/ You can do it both ways: turn x around, turn around x

The sentence is parsed: "the girl (subject) {turned down} (phrasal verb) the radio (direct object)."
to turn down (phrasal verb) = to reduce the volume or intensity [of something]
The radio is the direct object.
{down the radio} represents an erroneous parsing.
"down the radio" is not a constituent.

I asked my friends and they told me that in terms of substitution test, "it" can replace "down the radio" and we have "the girl turned it".

This is rubbish. Your friends might be nice people, but they do not speak English well.

'The girl turned it.' is certainly a bona-fide sentence (granted an antecedent in a prior sentence).. This is probably what is throwing the analysts; they're missing the second part of the rule ('It-substitution can be effected leaving a grammatical sentence (perhaps with relocation of the 'it') with the same meaning.

@EdwinAshworth Not in this context it isn't. It's a misparse. Please try to pay attention to actual context. This person is right, it's rubbish.

@Lambie I'm trying to explain where the error might originate. Have you never taught?

@EdwinAshworth Of course, I taught English for seven years, in fact.  The point is for them to understand: to turn down, which then makes your interpretation moot.
